# Is merge needed for hibernate save? how does Cascade work?

Tags: hibernate

I have a Parent class with child class like below

```
 class Parent{
          private child; 

     } 

 Class Child {........ some variables; }
```

We are merging the oldObject and newObject when any changes are made on UI. 
now while saving the data using hibernate, it is passing the data to DAO layer but saving in data.

Do I need to use merge function?

Answer (score 0):

For sake of clarity, let us assume you are doing the following in your data code:

```
public void updateMyEntity(TheEntity oldEntity) {
  final Session session = openSession();
  try {
    session.getTransaction().begin();

    TheEntity attachedEntity = session.find( TheEntity.class, oldEntity.getId() );
    copyDataFromDetachedEntityToAttached( oldEntity, attachedEntity );

    session.getTransaction().commit();        
  }
  catch ( Exception e ) {
    if ( session != null && session.getTransaction().isActive() ) {
      session.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
    throw e;
  }
  finally {
    if ( session != null && session.isOpen() ) {
      session.close();
    }
  }
}
```

If `TheEntity` consists of some basic or cascade-enabled associations, you can easily ignore the call to *merge* and just alter the attached object.  During the commit, Hibernate will execute a flush which will implicitly merge the changes made to any attached objects in the persistence context.

Now the caveat here is if `TheEntity` has any associations that are not cascade enabled.  If thats the case, you will need to handle the appropriate persistence for any newly added associations.

Answer (score 0):

Went through the caasecade options on google. save-update worked for me.